# Kinect + Visual Studio 2013 LNK errors, how to properly link the library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, kinect-sdk

I downloaded kinect sdk both 1.8, and 2.0. I then created a new project, and edited its properties via **C/C++** and included x86 headers folders

[image]

I also edited its **Linker** and added its corresponding x86 libraries folder.

[image]

Yet I still get linking errors, and it's not clear to me what it may be.

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__NuiInitialize@4 referenced in function _wmain
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Any idea? Not sure what else I can do in the linker settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem resolved,

In addition to

1. C/C++ include
2. Linker library

You also need to edit

3. Linker Input
   In here you add Kinect10.lib (or Kinect20.lib, depending on what version you're using)

[image]